# Error handling block not executing in snowflake using SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to implement error handling in snowflake using `Try Catch` block. Enclosed SQL queries in javascript for applying error handling. When I execute the query it executes return statement directly and none of the queries inside `Try Catch` block runs.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_N_1Test"("STAGE_S3" VARCHAR(16777216), "STAGE_OUTPUT" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE Javascript
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$

var cmd = `truncate table STAGE2A.T001_IRF_STUDENT_FORM_S3`;
var my_sql_command1 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
var result = my_sql_command1.execute();

var cmd1 = `''COPY INTO STAGE2A.T001_IRF_STUDENT_FORM_S3 
FROM ( select
FN_TrimStr($1) as   State,
FN_TrimStr($2) as   AdminCode,    
from @stage2a.''||:STAGE_S3||'') 
pattern= ''''.*_IRF_.*\\\\.csv''''
file_format = (type=csv, skip_header=1 )''`;
var my_sql_command2 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd1});
var result1 = my_sql_command2.execute();

var cmd2 = `Insert into STAGE2B.T011_IRF_STUDENT_FORM_V001 (
   STATE_FLAG,
    STATE_CD,
    )
SELECT
   STATE_FLAG,
    STATE_CD,
    from  STAGE2A.V001_IRF_STUDENT_FORM_T001`;
var my_sql_command3 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd2});
var result2 = my_sql_command3.execute();

return;
$$;
```

Also, I want to print a message in each `Try` block to output success when it runs successfully. I've used `Print, Println, sustem.print.out()` but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have some confusion about calling SQL statements inside the procedure. You need to use snowflake API to call SQLs:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript.html

What I see here is:

```
try{ `truncate table "STAGE2A"."T001_IRF_STUDENT_FORM_S3"`;} -- nothing to execute
catch (err){}
try{
`bla bla bla bla`; --- nothing to execute
return "Load process completed for IRF_STUDENT_FORM_S3"; 
}
catch(err){}
```

You opened backtick (`) and closed it before the return command, making everything template string. This is why you see the function returns immediately. As I said, you need to check how to use snowflake API to call the SQLs.

About writing an output, you can't write an output like this but you can define a variable and return it, or you can insert the logs to a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test("STAGE_S3" VARCHAR(16777216), "STAGE_OUTPUT" VARCHAR(16777216))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE Javascript
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
'
var result = "";

try{ `truncate table "STAGE2A"."T001_IRF_STUDENT_FORM_S3"`;
   result += "table truncated ";
}
catch (err){}
...
result += "Load process completed for IRF_STUDENT_FORM_S3";

}

catch(err){}

return result; 
';
```

Comment: I've tried below but sp returns null

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad It could be better to share the latest version of your function (you may update your question). I hope you read the documentation I mentioned and fixed the SQL calls.

Comment: I've updated the code in my question which I recently updated. I've only truncating the table but not copying and inserting the records. Output I get is Null.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad return command doesn't return anything. You need to return some value like: return result + result1 + result2;

Comment: Thanks for the help, last thing if you can check the syntax of SQL in ```cmd2``` I'm getting syntax error. Most likely I'm using the wrong delimiters ```'``` , ```''```, ```"```

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad it seems there are additional **commas** after STATE_CD: .Insert into STAGE2B.T011_IRF_STUDENT_FORM_V001 (
   STATE_FLAG,
    STATE_CD,
    )
SELECT
   STATE_FLAG,
    STATE_CD,
    from  STAGE2A.V001_IRF_STUDENT_FORM_T001

Comment: The commas look good to me because I'm getting following error ```SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected ''''. At Statement.execute, line 64 position 30```

Comment: @AfzaalAhmad no, the command has syntax error because of commas. As I see, the same error also exists on the COPY statement. On the other hand, I can see that there are more **syntax errors** in your SQL statements. Please make sure that the SQLs can be executed stand-alone. Have you tried to run your COPY command? Does it support your FN_TrimStr function? If so, can you share the code of FN_TrimStr?

Comment: These SQLs are running fine when language is SQL, I've used same SQLs here inside the API. FN_TrimStr is working fine in SQL I'm not sure if this works inside the javascript

Comment: ````                                                                                                                                 
`COPY INTO STAGE2A.T001_IRF_STUDENT_FORM_S3 
FROM ( 
select
FN_TrimStr($1) as State,
FN_TrimStr($2) as AdminCode,current_user() as Created_By,
current_timestamp() as Created_Date      
from @stage2a.stg_S3_NMC_Delivery_and_Scoring_PII) 
pattern= ''''.*_IRF_.*\\\\.csv''''
file_format = (type=csv, skip_header=1)`;                                                                                                     ```